# My JSON file has the data encoded rather than as an array how can I change this?

Tags: json, tiled

I'm using phaser for my game and with a **JSON** file that has an array of numbers for the data, the game is working, but when I'm exporting my custom maps I've made on Tiled the data is coming out like this:

```
"compression":"zlib",               "data":"eJxjYBgF9AZ5QJwPxAVUNLMOiOuBuIGKZvYBcT8QT6CimaNgFIyCUUBPAACmvgR4",
"encoding":"base64",
```

and I want it to just be like this for example:

```
"data":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
```

I don't know why its exporting like this and it is the only thing that is different between the working **JSON** file I'm using and the ones I have made.

Comment: something might be wrong with the logic you used to export.

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal Tiled does all of that I just select export and choose the format.

Comment: "eJxjYBgF9AZ5QJwPxAVUNLMOiOuBuIGKZvYBcT8QT6CimaNgFIyCUUBPAACmvgR4" is this what you want to export as [e,j,x,j....]

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal No, I want it to be the original array of numbers, which are the numbers of the position in the tileset. It's changing the array of numbers to this weird letter format which I don't want.

Comment: you might be having something like Arrays.toString() method, it will return the array in your desired format.

Answer (score 7):

Change the Tile Layer Format on Map -> Map Properties to CSV or XML format (As long as it's not compressed or encoded to Base64) and then export as a json file.
Good luck with you game!

Comment: CSV will be the default format starting with Tiled 0.15.